# hp-setup can't find printer connected with USB

Tags: printing, cups, hp-printer

I'm having trouble with my HP LaserJet P1102 on an Arch Linux 4.19.2 system.

`lsusb` shows that the printer is connected:

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 03f0:002a HP, Inc LaserJet P1102
```

In `journalctl`, I see these messages when plugging in the printer via USB:

```
kernel: usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
kernel: usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=03f0, idProduct=002a, bcdDevice= 1.00
kernel: usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
kernel: usb 2-1.1: Product: HP LaserJet Professional P1102
kernel: usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
kernel: usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: 000000000Q80X0EGSI1c
kernel: usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
kernel: scsi host6: usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0
mtp-probe[14854]: checking bus 2, device 7: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1"
mtp-probe[14854]: bus: 2, device: 7 was not an MTP device
mtp-probe[14867]: checking bus 2, device 7: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1"
mtp-probe[14867]: bus: 2, device: 7 was not an MTP device
```

But when running `sudo hp-setup -i` and selecting 0 to check for USB-connected printers I get:

```
Using connection type: usb

error: No device selected/specified or that supports this functionality.
```

Output of `systemctl status org.cups.cupsd.service`:

```
● org.cups.cupsd.service - CUPS Scheduler
  Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/org.cups.cupsd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-11-23 13:03:23 CET; 25min ago
    Docs: man:cupsd(8)
Main PID: 6271 (cupsd)
  Status: "Scheduler is running..."
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
  Memory: 7.5M
  CGroup: /system.slice/org.cups.cupsd.service
          └─6271 /usr/bin/cupsd -l
```

`sudo hp-check` crashes:

```
HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.18.6)
Dependency/Version Check Utility ver. 15.1

Copyright (c) 2001-15 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Note: hp-check can be run in three modes:
1. Compile-time check mode (-c or --compile): Use this mode before compiling the HPLIP supplied tarball (.tar.gz or .run) to determine if the proper   
dependencies are installed to successfully compile HPLIP.                                                                                              
2. Run-time check mode (-r or --run): Use this mode to determine if a distro supplied package (.deb, .rpm, etc) or an already built HPLIP supplied     
tarball has the proper dependencies installed to successfully run.                                                                                     
3. Both compile- and run-time check mode (-b or --both) (Default): This mode will check both of the above cases (both compile- and run-time            
dependencies).                                                                                                                                         

Check types:                                                                                                                                           
a. EXTERNALDEP - External Dependencies                                                                                                                 
b. GENERALDEP - General Dependencies (required both at compile and run time)                                                                           
c. COMPILEDEP - Compile time Dependencies                                                                                                              
d. [All are run-time checks]                                                                                                                           
PYEXT SCANCONF QUEUES PERMISSION                                                                                                                       

Status Types:
    OK
    MISSING       - Missing Dependency or Permission or Plug-in
    INCOMPAT      - Incompatible dependency-version or Plugin-version

-Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/hplip/base/utils.py", line 266, in walkFiles
    names = os.listdir(root)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/PolicyKit'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/hplip/base/utils.py", line 268, in walkFiles
    raise StopIteration
StopIteration

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/hp-check", line 861, in <module>
    dep.core.init()
  File "/usr/share/hplip/installer/core_install.py", line 500, in init
    self.check_dependencies(callback)
  File "/usr/share/hplip/installer/core_install.py", line 593, in check_dependencies
    self.have_dependencies[d] = self.dependencies[d][3]()
  File "/usr/share/hplip/installer/core_install.py", line 1164, in check_policykit
    if check_file('PolicyKit.conf', "/etc/PolicyKit") and check_file('org.gnome.PolicyKit.AuthorizationManager.service', "/usr/share/dbus-1/services"):
  File "/usr/share/hplip/installer/dcheck.py", line 108, in check_file
    for w in utils.walkFiles(dir, recurse=True, abs_paths=True, return_folders=False, pattern=f):
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
```

All packages are updated to their latest version, meaning `sudo pacman -Syu` says "there is nothing to do".

I've got Python 3.7.1 installed via pacman.

Is this a bug in HP's software? An incompatibility introduced with a newer Python version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by uninstalling and then reinstalling hplip:

```
sudo pacman -R hplip && sudo pacman -S hplip
```

After that, I could install HP's driver plug-in again with

```
sudo hp-setup -i
```

although downloading the GPG key failed with

> error: Unable to recieve [sic] key from keyserver

Printing a test page on the HP LaserJet P1102 using `system-config-printer` works now.

`sudo hp-check` doesn't crash either anymore:

```
HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.19.1)
Dependency/Version Check Utility ver. 15.1
...
```

Some versions for reference:

- Linux kernel: `5.0.4`
- hplip package `1:3.19.1-1`
- cups package: `2.2.10-2`

### Addendum

This problem reoccurred causing me to give up on HP printers and switch to Brother. There are some links regarding that at the bottom of [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/359531/installing-hp-printer-driver-for-arch-linux#392629).